# Cosa vuol dire "sotto col fosforo" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Continuavo a trovare strano che l’uomo, svissero e coi piedi in terra, si fosse lasciato convincere da quel visionario fanatico, e con l’occasione, cautamente, gli accennai il mio giudizio, ma mi rispose brutalmente che non era affare mio criticare i professori. Mi fece capire che non ero pagato per niente, e mi invitò a non perdere tempo, e ad incominciare subito col fosforo: lui era convinto che il fosforo ci avrebbe certamente condotti ad una brillante soluzione. **Sotto col fosforo**.

Questo "svissero" fa riferimento a quello che si spiega in questo passaggio:

> Il Commendatore mi fece poche domande, rispose evasivamente alle mie molte, e si dimostrò uomo concreto su due punti fondamentali. Lo stipendio iniziale che mi proponeva ammontava ad una cifra che io non avrei mai osato chiedere, e che mi lasciò attonito; la sua industria era svizzera, anzi, lui stesso era svizzero (lui pronunciava «svissero»), quindi per la mia eventuale assunzione non c’erano difficoltà. Trovai strano, anzi, francamente comico il suo svizzerismo espresso con un cosí virulento accento milanese; [...].

Il "visionario fanatico" è un tale Doktor Kerrn, che in un libro aveva esposto delle teorie sugli effetti del fosforo sui diabetici. L'autore si riferisce in questo modo a tale libro:

> Era un libro strano: difficilmente avrebbe potuto essere stato scritto e stampato altrove che nel Terzo Reich. L’autore [...]. Scriveva, anzi concionava, come un profeta invasato, come se il metabolismo del glucosio, nel diabetico e nel sano, gli fosse stato rivelato da Geova sul Sinai, anzi, da Wotan sul Walhalla.

Non capisco il significato della locuzione "sotto col fosforo" che appare nel primo brano. Ho cercato alla voce "sotto" di parecchi dizionari, inclusi il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sotto/) e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000587.jpg)], [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000588.jpg)], [[3](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000589.jpg)], [[4](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000590.jpg)], [[5](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000591.jpg)], [[6](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000592.jpg)], [[7](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000593.jpg)] e [[8](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000594.jpg)]), ma non riesco a vedere quale possa essere il senso di questa espressione. Forse il problema è che ci siano tantissime accezioni. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare cosa significa?

Comment: "Sotto col fosforo" è un po' come "avanti col fosforo", "ale' con il fosforo", "giù con il fosforo", "via col fosforo", anche "daje col fosforo": insomma fare uso, o comunque coinvolgere, o iniziare a usare; è un tono enfatico e colorito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'espressione che hai trovato è un'esortazione (che l'autore fa a se stesso) e deriva da questa accezione di "sotto" ([Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sotto/))

> **mettersi s**., attendere con accanimento a un lavoro, allo studio, e sim.

"Sotto col fosforo" è quindi l'esortazione a intraprendere lo studio/analisi della materia (il fosforo) senza perdere tempo e con la massima lena.

Comment: Se si tratta di un'esortazione, potrebbe anche corrispondere all'accezione 38 del [GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000591.jpg)? Ah! Adesso vedo che appare appunto come esempio la citazione di Levi che ho messo nella domanda. Scusatemi, mi era proprio sfuggito: è difficile leggere 8 pagine di questo dizionario senza saltare assolutamente nulla. Riccardo: se vuoi, puoi aggiungerlo alla risposta.